# Setting multiple IP addresses on private network interface using Vagrant

Tags: networking, virtualbox, ip, vagrant

I am trying to configure IPv4 and IPv6 address on Internal network Vagrant interface but I am unable to do so.

Here is the configuration:

```
  config.vm.network "private_network", 
      ip: "192.168.30.10",
      ip: "fd::10",
      virtualbox__intnet: true,
      bridge: "eth1"
  config.vm.network "private_network",
      ip: "192.168.40.10",
      virtualbox__intnet: true,
      bridge: "eth2"
```

Ideally I would love to setup link-local address manually but I got error when booting up VM. For now I can work with private IPv6 addresses. Is the only way to turn off auto-config and set it up inside VM?

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely [Disable Auto-Configuration](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/private_network.html) using the `auto_config` property as shown below:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.30.10",
    auto_config: false
end
```

Then you can just run some shell provisioners later on to configure them how you want them:

```
  # default router
  config.vm.provision "shell",
    run: "always",
    inline: "route add default gw 192.168.0.1"

  # default router ipv6
  config.vm.provision "shell",
    run: "always",
    inline: "route -A inet6 add default gw fc00::1 eth1"

  # delete default gw on eth0
  config.vm.provision "shell",
    run: "always",
    inline: "eval `route -n | awk '{ if ($8 ==\"eth0\" && $2 != \"0.0.0.0\") print \"route del default gw \" $2; }'`"
```